# Calculate rotation on a sphere with given coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I have a sphere with a fixed radius. 
I have a set of points on that sphere, let's say $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ and it's $3$D Cartesian coordinates.

I rotated each of the points around the center of the sphere with the rotation matrix $M$ and get the set of $p_{1r}, p_{2r}, p_{3r}$ cartesian coordinates.

How can I calculate the matrix $M$ if I know that points coordinates?

Comment: This might not be the best way, but you can assume $M$ is some $3\times3$ matrix that when multiplied with a matrix with the columns of $p_1,p_2,p_3$, gives you a matrix with the columns of $p_{1r},p_{2r},p_{3r}$. That's $9$ equations for $9$ unknowns.

Comment: @user137794 I recently found this approach http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm what do you think can I use it? I am not a mathematician so can't be sure. But it looks very close to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Rotations of sphere are linear transformations, so you can use formula from "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner%27s_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Linear transformations".
Let's treat rotated points as vectors $\vec{p}_{1r}$, $\vec{p}_{2r}$, $\vec{p}_{3r}$, the answer can be written in the following neat form
$$
\vec{R}(p^x; p^y; p^z) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0   & \vec{p}_{1r} & \vec{p}_{2r} & \vec{p}_{3r} \\
            p^x & p_1^x        & p_2^x        & p_3^x        \\
            p^y & p_1^y        & p_2^y        & p_3^y        \\
            p^z & p_1^z        & p_2^z        & p_3^z        \\
        \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            p_1^x        & p_2^x        & p_3^x        \\
            p_1^y        & p_2^y        & p_3^y        \\
            p_1^z        & p_2^z        & p_3^z        \\
        \end{pmatrix}
},
$$
where upper indices designate components ($x$, $y$, $z$); $p^x$, $p^y$, and $p^z$ are coordinates of the point you are mapping.
Expanding matrix in the numerator along the first column and rearranging everything you can get canonical form -- matrix times vector.
General procedure of the matrix recovery is described in the "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner%27s_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "canonical form", or you can check for concrete example in "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Linear transformation by points".